# Issue with MATLAB IRIS Perceptron

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron, iris-recognition

[Link to the github page with all of the code](https://github.com/jweissenberger/Matlab-Neural-Net)

Sorry but this is a shot in the dark. I have been trying to get this MATLAB perceptron to classify the iris data set for months now. I have tried changing the hyper parameters, activation function, different forms of gradient descent, initialisation, gradient checking and many other things but I cannot get it to work. If anyone can give me any clues as to why it is not working it would be greatly appreciated.

```
%% Define Hyperparameters
% This will be a 4 layer neural network, with two hidden layers

inputLayerSize = 4; % representing the 4 features 
outputLayerSize = 3; % representing the 3 kinds of iris
hiddenLayer1Size = 6;
hiddenLayer2Size = 5;


%% Randomly Initialize Weights and Biases

W12 = rand(hiddenLayer1Size, inputLayerSize);
b12 = rand(hiddenLayer1Size, 1);
W23 = rand(hiddenLayer2Size, hiddenLayer1Size);
b23 = rand(hiddenLayer2Size, 1);
W34 = rand(outputLayerSize, hiddenLayer2Size);
b34 = rand(outputLayerSize, 1);

%% Number of iterations of training 
for i = 1 : 100

%% Randomly Select Training Example
% Because this neural network is trained using Stochastic gradient descent
% the network is trained using only one example

[~,s] = size(X_train);
n = randi(s);
Xone = X_train(:,n);
Yone = Y_train(:,n);

%% Forward Propagation

[Yout, a3, a2, z4, z3, z2] = ForwardProp( Xone, W12, b12, W23, b23, W34, b34 );

%% Back Propagation

[del4, del3, del2] = Backprop(Yout, Yone, z4, z3, z2, W34, W23);

%% Update Weights and bias

nu = 0.1; %learning rate

W34 = W34 - nu * (del4*a3');
b34 = b34 - nu * del4;

W23 = W23 - nu * (del3*a2');
b23 = b23 - nu * del3;

W12 = W12 - nu * (del2*Xone');
b12 = b12 - nu * del2;


%% Check Accuracy
if rem(i, 10) == 0
[ Ycheck, a3, a2, z4, z3, z2 ] = ForwardProp( X_test, W12, b12, W23, b23, W34, b34 );
AccuracyCheck(Ycheck, Y_test)

end 
end
```

Comment: Why is it not working? What do you get and what do you expect to get?

Comment: the weights keep updating but they never update enough to change the actual prediction of the network and usually each of the outputted predictions are so close to each other they are practically the same fro each  kind of outputted example